# How to determine the block size used by the file system by using a C program that performs incremental read()'s?

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems

I am preparing for my exams by doing some textbook practice questions. I am stuck at one of the questions which asks us to find the block size used by the our computers file system by using a C program that performs read()'s of increasing sizes.

The textbook gives us this hint:

---

Use reads of varying sizes (make sure the sizes are big enough) analyze the time it takes to do such reads. Sequential reads may affected by prefetching so take this into account.

---

I am confused about the following:

1) I dont get how performing reads of incrementing sizes would help 
determine the block size?

2) What does it mean by `Sequential reads may affected by prefetching so take this into account.`?

3) When incrementing the size each round, do I have to read from the start every time? Or keep reading from the point I started?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quickest time will be when the size you request is the same as, or a multiple of, the system's buffer size. If your request is less, it will somtimes require the system to bridge a block boundary, requiring 2 reads form disk. If it is larger, it will *always* require two reads from disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, what a stupid text book.

> 1) I dont get how performing reads of incrementing sizes would help determine the block size?

The block size will be a power of 2. Theoretically, if you do a read of

2^0, 2^1, 2^2, . . . . 2^N

bytes from the start of a file (or offset from a block boundary) those operations will take the same amount of time until N exceeds the block size (i.e, requires 2 reads to service).

> 2) What does it mean by Sequential reads may affected by prefetching so take this into account.?

If you read the first block in the file, the OS may fetch the second block and cache it in anticipation of wanting the next block. That would throw off the timings. So you'd need to read from random locations.

> 3) When incrementing the size each round, do I have to read from the start every time? Or keep reading from the point I started?

You want to read from a random location but that location should be a multiple of a power of 2 that will be larger than the the block size (e.g., 2^20). If you use any old random value, you could be doing 2 block reads, even for a just 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm idea

Try different sizes and note the time it takes to read `X` bytes by reading a trial "block" at a time.

I would not "read from the start every time" nor "keep reading from the point I started", between sub-tests but seek ahead to avoid using pre-fetched data.

---

Write a *big* file filled with random data as set-up.

Assume the block size is `S1smallest, S2, S3, S4, ... or SnLargest` bytes.  ( like 100, 256, 1000, 1024, 4096, 65536, etc.

Let `n = 100`.

1) Starting at `addr=0`

2) Read `n*S5Largest` bytes of data in total, `S1smallest` bytes at a time.  Report the elapsed time.

3) `fseek()` `n*S5Largest` bytes past where you are.  (this is to get well past any pre-fetched data.)

4) repeat step 2) with size `S2` instead of `S1smallest`. and step 3)

5) Do step 4) for the remaining sizes `S3 .... SnLargest`.

The best time is a good candidate winner.  Try same test in reverse order of block sizes to insure you have consistent results.

Pre-calculate the size needed to do this test to insure the original file was big enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that suggested hints (in book) is right way to get block size due to following reasons

(1) File systems can have variable blocks internally.

(2) Prefetch is more internal implementation and in general its goal to ensure the read is served from in-memory (i.e without disk I/O cost) especially for sequential reads.

One approach for block size (at least for on-disk file system and fixed block sizes) i can think:

In general, the file system block size will be 4K, 8K, 16K, 32K, 64K etc (multiples of 4K). In UNIX there will be "du(1) " which gives the file actual consumption on disk.

One can create file with varying file size of different bytes and can get to know on which multiple blocks size(s) the file is growing.